# show/hide in mysql result function in first result only

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$('#varx2').click(function() {
    $("#txt").toggle(this.checked);
});
});
</script>

<?php
print "<table>";
if($items)
foreach($items as $i){
print "<tr>";
print"<td><input type='checkbox' id='varx2' name='checkbox[]' value='$i->logi_id'/></td>"; //CHECKBOX
print "<td id='txt' style='display:none'>$i->logi_jo</td>";
print "<td>$i->logi_cntrlnum</td>";
print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
?>
```

gud day, this is a show/hide java script.. when i click or check the checkbox, the row will extent beside, the problem is only the first row/result is extending.. can u pls help me.. ty

Answer (score 1):

IDs *must* be unique, ID selector only selects the first element that has a specific ID, you should use classes instead:

```
print "<td class='txt' style='display:none'>$i->logi_jo</td>";
```

Comment: i try this sir. but it is not working, and the first row is not extending nahh XD ty for response

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion You are welcome, please post the rendered markup.

Comment: Sir. undefined if i need to change it to class the # in varx should become .?

Comment: @RobertJohnConcepcion Yes, for class selectors you should use `$('.yourClass')`

Comment: still not working sir T_T.. i think this problem will provide a nice head ache hahaha

Comment: Sir it this possible that the id should be like this id='varx2[]' for them to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

Id's for each element need to be unique.  JQuery will just select the first one, unlike a class selector for example will select all elements with a class.  Try set the id to the item id or name or something else unique.

Answer (score 0):

Remove id and put it as a class.

jQuery function will be

```
$('.varx2').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
// do whatever you want
});
})
```

Comment: did you change id to class?
Should be like
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='varx2' name='checkbox[]' value='$i->logi_id'/></td>

And Jquery function can be like this

$('.varx2').click(function(){});

Comment: it works.. but the problem is.. when i click 1 checkbox it all expanded.. i need is when row 1 checkbox is click, only row 1 will expand.. if i put check in row 3 only row three will expand..

Comment: Your jquery selector might selecting all. try like this $('.varx2').click(function(){ $(this).parent().siblings('#txt').fadeIn(); }); Note: you can replace fadeIn with your function or animation you would like.

Comment: whats should i replace of this: $('.varx2').click(function(){ $(this).parent().siblings('#txt').fadeIn(); }); ????????

Comment: fadeIn is the function I added . so replace that fadeIn with what you want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16223/discussion-between-robert-john-concepcion-and-kiran-ambati)